# Why does my code jump to else immediately?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int printMenu(int);
int studentglobal;
float getCarryMark(float);
float cm1;


main()
{
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\tTotal Score calculator\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    int counter, x, studentcount = 1,sum = 0 ;

    x = printMenu(studentglobal);

    for (counter = 0; counter < x; counter++)

    {
        studentcount = studentcount + counter;
        printf("Student : %d \n", studentcount);
        getCarryMark(cm1);

        if (cm1 >= 0 && cm1 <= 50)
        {
            printf("right range!!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID RANGE!!!\n");
        }
        printf("%.2f\n", cm1);
    }

}

int printMenu(int nstudent)
{
    printf("Enter no of student: ");
    scanf("%d", &nstudent);
    return(nstudent);
}

float getCarryMark(float carrymark)
{
    printf("Enter your carrymarks: ");
    scanf("%f", &carrymark);
    return(carrymark);
}
```

So actually when I enter 200, it shows `INVALID RANGE!!!`, but when I enter 20 it still shows `INVALID RANGE!!!`. It somehow skipped the if statement. Please don't bother the other part, if I have any mistake tell me please. ert gf dfg dgd dg dfgd gd dg dg dgdfg

Comment: First, compile with warnings on. That should make the problem obvious.

Comment: Second, test your `getCarryMark()` method in isolation. If the warning from the compiler didn't help, this will.

Comment: ...and, since  no-one flagged it, in `getCarryMark(carrymark)` the parameter `carrymark` is an `int`, not a `double`. A `scanf` to that parameter can cause problems because they are not the same size.

Comment: 'float getCarryMark(float carrymark)
{
 printf("Enter your carrymarks: ");
 scanf("%f", &carrymark);
 return(carrymark);
}'

Comment: when i enter carrymarks it print 0.00 !! @PaulOgilvie

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i editted the question

Comment: ...then you haven't learned from all the comments and answers... Change to: `getCarryMark(&cm1);` or to `cm1=getCarryMark();` and adjust the functions accordingly. Oh, don't forget to __read__ (and _understand_!) all the good answers!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return carrymark from getCarryMark:

```
float getCarryMark(float carrymark)
{
    printf("Enter your carrymarks: ");
    scanf("%f", &carrymark);
    return(carrymark);
}
```

Comment: `float getCarryMark(carrymark)` should be `float getCarryMark(float carrymark)` and float variable pass to this, not int.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY better yet, change the signature to read `float getCarryMark(void);`. There's no reason to return the result in both an output parameter AND in the return value. Returning by return value is more idiomatic anyway.

Comment: Why pass an argument to the function only to overwrite it with the result of `scanf()`?  The argument should be removed; `carrymark` should be a local variable, the value of which is returned to the calling code.  Then the call needs to be `cm1 = getCarryMark();` of course.  And we can ask why on earth `cm1` is a global variable – it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a return statement in getCarryMarks method !

Comment: already add it now it always show if statement...//right rage//

Comment: @Shaik if that was it please accept my answer pressing the tick. Regards!

Answer (score 2):

You missed the return statement in getCarryMark

Answer (score 2):

**getCarryMark** function takes a parameter by value, modifies the value and returns it back, however, the returned value is never used. Modifying the parameter's value does not reflect this change to the outside since it has been passed by value.

I have partially updated the code so that it could execute the if statement. Please try the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int printMenu(int);
int studentglobal;
float getCarryMark(float);
float cm1;


main()
{
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\tTotal Score calculator\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    int counter, x, studentcount = 1,sum = 0 ;

    x = printMenu(studentglobal);

    for (counter = 0; counter < x; counter++)

    {
        studentcount = studentcount + counter;
        printf("Student : %d \n", studentcount);
        cm1 = getCarryMark();

        if (cm1 >= 0 && cm1 <= 50)
        {
            printf("right range!!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID RANGE!!!\n");
        }
        printf("%.2f\n", cm1);
    }

}

int printMenu(int nstudent)
{
    printf("Enter no of student: ");
    scanf("%d", &nstudent);
    return(nstudent);
}

float getCarryMark()
{
    float carrymark = 0.0;

    printf("Enter your carrymarks: ");
    scanf("%f", &carrymark);
    return(carrymark);
}
```